# Banach Algebra Counterexample

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Can someone give me an example of a Banach Algebra which does not have an isometric representation in a Hilbert Space ?

(if possible, can you add a proof or a reference ? )

Thank you very much !

---

**Note added by YC**: this question has also been [asked on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423702/banach-algebra-counterexample) where someone has given a much better, elementary example to the OP's question. (However, my example also works for the question of topologically isomorphic representations, not just the isometric ones.)

Comment: The Wiener algebra $A(\mathbb{T})$ is not an operator algebra.  
 

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think if you take any Banach $^*$ algebra that does not have a $C^*$-norm (eg $$L^1(G)$ for a locally compact group $G$) then you cannot represent the $\textit{algebra}$ on a Hilbert space. Note for the example I gave above you can represent the Banach space $L^1(G)$ on a Hilbert space, but as far as I know it will not be a representation of the algebra.

Comment: Thank you Owen. To be honest, im just an undergraduate student trying to learn something on my free time, so im sorry if my questions are easy at an absurd level. Anyway, where can you give me at least some references regarding the algebras on groups ? Thank you.

Comment: @jpp: Conway's book "A course in Functional Analysis" is a fairly standard text for a grad course in Functional Analysis. It has the basics on of what I was saying. In particular, it shows that the usual norm on $L^1(G)$ is not a $C^*$-norm and thus cannot be the norm on a subalgebra of B($\mathcal{H})$. 

Comment: @jpp: You should also note that if you take any Banach space, X, (so in particular the underlying Banach space of a Banach algebra). Then the weak$^*$-unit ball of the dual space is compact by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem. Then X embedds into $X^**$ and so it sits inside the space of continuous function on the unit ball in the dual. Thus by Gelfand-Naimark theorem can be realized as a subspace of B($\mathcal{H})$. When you do this for a Banach algebra though, in general the algebra structure will not carry over.

Comment: @jpp: Sorry for the comment spam. But after 2 seconds of thought I realized that in the example I gave in the previous comment. The image will \textit{never} be an algebra. This is because you are representing $X$ in a commutative algebra which means that multiplication is pointwise. However, the elements of $X$ are linear and when you pointwise multiply linear functions they are no longer linear.

Comment: @Owen Sizemore : Thank you very much for the reference and the attention :)

Comment: @Owen: it is not obvious that you can't embed the group algebra into B(H) via some homomorphism that isn't a star-map. (Something like the failure of von Neumann's inequality works in the case of A(T), the example Cedric gave; this is explained in the book of Diestel, Jarchow and Tonge)

Comment: @jpp: if you're posting a question both here and on math.stackexchange, please tell this in the post, and include a link. This will prevent duplication of effort by people. 

(Shouldn't this be in the faq or something?)

Comment: @jpp: over at math.stackexchange.com, please post a link back to this question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any Banach algebra which is not Arens regular cannot be embedded as a closed subalgebra of B(H), even if you allow for isomorphic embeddings that have closed range yet are not isometric.

If you are only interested in Banach $\ast$-algebras and isometric $\ast$-homomorphic embeddings, then it is easier to find examples, as Owen Sizemore has indicated.

---

**[Not directly relevant, but perhaps of background interest to the OP]**
By the way, although the question asks about isometric embeddings, there are interesting and slightly unexpected examples of Banach algebras $A$ for which there is an injective homomorphism $A\to B(\ell^2)$ that has closed range, showing that non-selfadjoint operator algebra theory has to be a lot wilder than the self-adjoint case. Examples include: $\ell^p$ for $1\leq p <\infty$ with pointwise product; and the algebras $C^k([0,1]^m)$ of $k$-times continuously differentiable functions on the $m$-cube. You can even get radical commutative Banach algebras embedded into $B(\ell^2)$ in this way, see

> [MR0410386 (53 #14136)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=410386) P. G. Dixon, *Radical Q-algebras.*
>   Glasgow Math. J. 17 (1976), no. 2, 119--126.